# Optimistic lock failed after REQUIRES_NEW transaction

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions, optimistic-locking

given the following scenario: two Spring beans, ServiceA and ServiceB, ServiceA loads an entity and then calls a method of bean ServiceB that loads and save the same entity.

After ServiceB method is completed, transaction is committed and the entity version is moved from 1 to 2.
After that call if I try to load again the same entity from ServiceA version is still 1.
Of course this cause the following exception on save call in ServiceA:

> Optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)

```
@Service
public class ServiceA {

    @Autowired
    private ServiceB serviceB;

    @Autowired
    private MyEntityRepository repo;

    @Transactional
    public void myMethod(Long id) {
        MyEntity e = repo.findById(id); -> version 1
        serviceB.doStuff(id);
        e = repo.findById(id); -> still version 1
        ...
        saveAndFlush(e); -> optimistic lock error
    }
}

@Service
public class ServiceB {

    @Autowired
    private MyEntityRepository repo;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void doStuff(Long id) {
        MyEntity e = repo.findById(id) -> version 1
        ...
        repo.saveAndFlush(e); -> version 2
    }
}
```

The only way to make it work is detach entity in ServiceA after doStuff() call, but it looks a dirty solution. Is there a better solution for this?

Used versions are:

- Hibernate: 5.4.6.FINAL
- Spring data JPA: 2.2.0.RELEASE

Comment: Make doStuff return the renewed entity

Comment: Not sure if you are aware about @Version. Here you have detailed explanation and solution - https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-optimistic-locking